# Android Beta Test Program - Item not found, 0 devices

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

I had difficulty with setting up my APK submission to the Android Beta Test Program.  At first I received 0 devices compatible, then I received Item not found.  It took me days to figure this out so I figured I'd post here.

-J

Answer (score 0):

For the 0 devices issue I changed my manifest to set the required features to false and I went from 0 devices to 2k+ (I require lollipop).

For the item not found this was more difficult and I ended up chatting with someone at Google who pointed out I had the APK restricted to my domain.  Once I found that, unchecked, and updated I was able to download from the url.

-J